# Getting a BeanCreationException in Kotlin Spring, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'movieRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract boolean no.kristiania.soj.groupexam.movie.MovieRepositoryCustom.update(long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,java.time.ZonedDateTime)! No property update found for type MovieEntity!

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract boolean no.kristiania.soj.groupexam.movie.MovieRepositoryCustom.update(long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,java.time.ZonedDateTime)! No property update found for type MovieEntity!
```

I'm making a crud repo for a movie, and I cannot find out why it keeps telling me that I am doing something wrong, these are my classes:

perhaps I'm overlooking something, but I've been rewriting and refactoring to try to find my mistake, to no avail.

Entity:

```
@Entity
class MovieEntity(
    @get:NotBlank
    var title: String,

    @get:NotBlank
    var director: String,

    @get:NotBlank
    var description: String,

    @get:NotBlank
    var info: String,

    @get:NotNull
    var rating: Int,

    @get:NotNull
    var releaseDate: ZonedDateTime,

    @get:Id
    @get:GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null
    )
```

Custom Repository

```
@Repository
interface MovieRepository : CrudRepository<MovieEntity, Long>, 
MovieRepositoryCustom

@Transactional
interface MovieRepositoryCustom {
fun createMovie(
        title: String,
        director: String,
        description: String,
        info: String,
        rating: Int,
        releaseDate: ZonedDateTime
) : Long

fun update(
        id: Long,
        title: String,
        director: String,
        description: String,
        info: String,
        rating: Int,
        releaseDate: ZonedDateTime
) : Boolean
}

@Repository
@Transactional
class MovieRepositoryImplementation : MovieRepositoryCustom {
@Autowired
private lateinit var entityManager: EntityManager

override fun createMovie(
        title: String,
        director: String,
        description: String,
        info: String,
        rating: Int,
        releaseDate: ZonedDateTime
): Long {
    val movie = MovieEntity(title, director, description, info, rating, releaseDate)
    entityManager.persist(movie)
    return movie.id!!
}

override fun update(
        id: Long,
        title: String,
        director: String,
        description: String,
        info: String,
        rating: Int,
        releaseDate: ZonedDateTime
) : Boolean {
    val movie = entityManager.find(MovieEntity::class.java, id) ?: return false

    movie.title = title
    movie.director = director
    movie.description = description
    movie.info = info
    movie.rating = rating
    movie.releaseDate = releaseDate

    return true
   }
}
```

I then try to run a test to check if it works, but then it gives me the error at the start:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = [(MovieApplication::class)],
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class RestTest {
@LocalServerPort
var port = 0

@Before
@After
fun clean() {
    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost"
    RestAssured.port = port
    RestAssured.basePath = "/movie"
    RestAssured.enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails()

    val list = RestAssured.given().accept(ContentType.JSON).get()
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .extract()
            .`as`(Array<MovieDTO>::class.java)
            .toList()

    list.stream().forEach {
        RestAssured.given().pathParam("id", it.id)
                .delete("/{id}")
                .then()
                .statusCode(204)
    }
    RestAssured.given().get()
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body("size()", CoreMatchers.equalTo(0))
}

@Test
fun testCreateMovie() {
    val title = "title"
    val director = "director"
    val description = "description"
    val info = "info"
    val rating = 4
    val releaseDate = ZonedDateTime.now()

    val dto = MovieDTO(title, director, description, info, rating, releaseDate)

    RestAssured.given().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            .get()
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body("size()", CoreMatchers.equalTo(0))

    val id = RestAssured.given().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            .body(dto)
            .post()
            .then()
            .statusCode(201)
            .extract().asString()

    RestAssured.given().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            .get()
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body("size()", CoreMatchers.equalTo(1))
    RestAssured.given().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            .pathParam("id", id)
            .get("/{id}")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body("title", CoreMatchers.equalTo(title))
            .body("director", CoreMatchers.equalTo(director))
            .body("description", CoreMatchers.equalTo(description))
            .body("info", CoreMatchers.equalTo(info))
            .body("rating", CoreMatchers.equalTo(rating))
            .body("releaseDate", CoreMatchers.equalTo(releaseDate))
            .body("id", CoreMatchers.equalTo(id))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this test for your repository implementation:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
class MovieRepositoryImplementationTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var movieRepository: MovieRepositoryImplementation

    @Test
    fun createAndUpdateAMovie() {
        val id = movieRepository.createMovie("title", "dir", "desc", "info", 5, ZonedDateTime.now())
        val wasUpdated = movieRepository.update(id, "title", "dir", "desc", "info", 5, ZonedDateTime.now())

        assertTrue(wasUpdated)
    }
}
```

I would also suggest to refactor your `createMovie` and `updateMovie` methods to accept a `MovieEntity` instead of individual fields. With your current implementation, if you add or remove fields from the movie, you have to update the method signature of your repository methods. Also, as the movie entity grows, the argument list will become really long...

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!